# How to make child element under parent float full width

Tags: html, css

I have a child element under a floated parent. How do I make the child element fullwidth without stretching the parent's width?

How it's now

[image: How it's now]

How I want it to work-- this has no float though

[image: How I want it to work-- this has no float though]

The only solution would be to remove it from the parent div, I would prefer not to!

```html
<div class="nome-squadra " style="float: left;">
  <p class="float-xl-left text orario mb-1">15:00 </p>
  <p class="text float-xl-left h4" id="nome-squadra">Roma - Napoli</p>
</div>
<div class="quoteCon" style="float: right;">
  <div class="quoteV container">
    <div class="row flex-row flex-nowrap esito"> code</div>
    <div class="row flex-row flex-nowrap quota" id="Roma - Napoli"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion pt-2" id="accordionTest0">
    <div id="quote0" class="collapse-div collapse show" role="tablist" style="">rest of code</div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use col-12 for parent .`<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 nome-squadra " style="float: left;">`
and for child `<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 quoteCon" style="float: right;">`with your style...
and use `style="width:100%;"` for inside element!